# Running thread workers with typescript (ts-node) on nodejs

Tags: node.js, worker, ts-node

Using node v14, typescript with ts-node v10.0.0

Here I'm offloading some work to workers.

```
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads')

console.log(process.pid)

function offloadToThread(workerData) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const worker = new Worker('./fib.ts', { workerData });
    worker.on('message', resolve);
    worker.on('error', reject);
    worker.on('exit', (code) => {
      if (code !== 0)
        reject(new Error(
          `Stopped the Worker Thread with the exit code: ${code}`));
    })
  })
}

async function run() {
  // trying to create 1000 threads
  for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    // find fibonacci from 1-20 and then repeat the process.
    offloadToThread(i % 20).then(r => { console.log(r, i) });
  }
}

run().catch(e => console.error(e))
```

Here, After compilation, code not able to pick correct js filename is obviously hardcoded.

I wonder why nodejs team did not look into this and made it such to work with files just like we use to import modules with

```js
require('/my-modules/1')  // does not require js at the end
```

but below code requires a valid .js file

```js
const worker = new Worker('./fib.js', { workerData }); // needs .js extension
```

Any way to resolve filename after typescript compilation to js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on ts-node version 10.0.0

This method will resolve filename if it is running under ts-node

```js
let fileResolver = function(filename:string){
  // @ts-ignore // check if code is not running under ts-node
  if (!process[Symbol.for("ts-node.register.instance")]) {
    return filename.replace('.ts','.js');
  }

  return filename;
}
```

found this here in issues https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/846